# Add to .gitignore in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

When I add a file to .gitignore changes in file are still tracked in Visual Studio Code.

The file is in the root where is .gitignore file added by VSC and file that should be ignored is entred in the .gitignore file by the VSC. The file name is `bs-config.js`

```
node_modules
vendor
bs-config.js
package-lock.json
```

[image: .gitignore file]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The system will ignore what you put inside `.gitignore` but if you already commit some file that you want ignore you should remove from the git repository, or committing a deletion

Answer (score 0):

You will be tracking changes within the `.gitignore` file, thats why you see those blue bars. that means your git instance is tracking changes in the `.gitignore` file. The files you add to `.gitignore` like your `bs-config.js` will be greyed out in VSCode's explorer view to let you know its untracked.